# Como agregar puntos decimales al ir escribiendo los valores numericos

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito que en la columna Costo al momento de tipear el valor numerico me separe en decimales ejemplo: 1.345.654

En este caso ya me han ayudado a resolver lo siguiente
Que al ingresar en la celda CANTIDAD algun valor numerico me multiplique por el COSTO automaticamente y el resultado se visualice en el input de total de sus fila, y luego de manera automatica sin ningun boton que me sume los totales al final
Tambien al momento de tipear los datos numericos en los input correspondientes a COSTO y CANTIDAD me separe con puntos decimales ejemplo= 2.345.543 y cuando multiplique CANTIDAD por COSTO se visualice en el input TOTAL tambien con puntos decimales

Todo esto ya esta hecho solo me faltaria que en la columna COSTO me separe con decimales al tipear los datos numericos

```js
function changeValores(id){
  let CantElement = document.getElementById("cant" + id);
  let ValorElement = document.getElementById("valor" + id);
  let TotalElement = document.getElementById("total" + id);
  
  let totalParcial = Number(CantElement.value) * Number(ValorElement.value);
  
  TotalElement.setAttribute("data-total",totalParcial);
  TotalElement.value = totalParcial.toLocaleString('es');
  actualizarTotales();
}

function actualizarTotales(){
   let TotalElement = document.getElementById("total");
   let suma=0;
   document.querySelectorAll("input[data-total]").forEach( e => suma += Number(e.getAttribute("data-total")));
   TotalElement.value = suma.toLocaleString('es');
}
```

```html
<form>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<td>Producto</td>
<td>Cantidad</td>
<td>Costo</td>
<td>Total</td>
<tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Puertas</td>
<td><input type="number" id="cant1" oninput="changeValores(1)" ></td>
<td><input type="number" id="valor1" value=""  oninput="changeValores(1)"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="total1"  data-total="" readonly></td>
<tr>

<tr>
<td>Puertas</td>
<td><input type="number" id="cant2" oninput="changeValores(2)" ></td>
<td><input type="number" id="valor2" value=""  oninput="changeValores(2)"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="total2" data-total="" readonly></td>
<tr>

</tbody>

<tfoot>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>Total</td>
<td><input type="text" id="total" readonly></td>
<tr>
</tfoot>
</table>


</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes hacer uso de `Intl.NumberFormat`.

> Documentacion: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat

```js
const number = 123456.789;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE').format(number));
//  output: "123.456,789"
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Agustin pero como hago funcionar con este metodo dentro de mi codigo??

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que para separar en cienes, miles y millones es con `,` y para los decimales es con `.`. Podrías utilizar expresiones regulares para separar cada 3 números con `,`:

```js
const numero = 43859382;
const numero2 = 59485.45;

const format = (number) => {
  const exp = /(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g;
  const rep = '$1,'; // Si quieres con puntos decimales, cambialo por '$1.'
  return number.toString().replace(exp,rep);
}

console.log(format(numero));  // 43,859,382
console.log(format(numero2)); // 59,485.45
```

Integrandolo en tu código, sería así:

```js
  function changeValores(id){
    let CantElement = document.getElementById("cant" + id);
    let ValorElement = document.getElementById("valor" + id);
    let TotalElement = document.getElementById("total" + id);

    let totalParcial = Number(CantElement.value) * Number(ValorElement.value);

    TotalElement.setAttribute("data-total",totalParcial);
    TotalElement.value = formatNumber(totalParcial);
    actualizarTotales();
  }

  function actualizarTotales(){
    let TotalElement = document.getElementById("total");
    let suma = 0;

    document.querySelectorAll("input[data-total]").forEach( e => suma += Number(e.getAttribute("data-total")));
    TotalElement.value = formatNumber(suma);
  }
  
  function formatNumber(number){
    const exp = /(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g;
    const rep = '$1,';
    return number.toString().replace(exp,rep);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
<form>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Producto</td>
        <td>Cantidad</td>
        <td>Costo</td>
        <td>Total</td>
      </tr>
      <tr></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Puertas</td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" id="cant1" oninput="changeValores(1)" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" id="valor1" value="" oninput="changeValores(1)"
          />
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="total1" data-total="" readonly /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Puertas</td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" id="cant2" oninput="changeValores(2)" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" id="valor2" value="" oninput="changeValores(2)"
          />
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="total2" data-total="" readonly /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="total" readonly /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr></tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda Cris pero como lo hago funcionar dentro de mi codigo esa es la gran pregunta

Comment: @MarceloJoseSosaSosa acabo de editar mi respuesta.

Comment: Cris los puntos decimales necesito que se aplique en la columna costo

Comment: *se visualice en el input TOTAL tambien con puntos decimales* -> a esto no te referías?

Comment: Hola Cris en el input TOTAL se visualiza con puntos decimales eso ya esta listo osea ya funciona ahora lo que necesito es que en el input COSTO en el momento de ingresar un valor numerico tambin me separe por decimales